# How to say "protective cover"?

Tags: vocabulaire, adjectifs, noms

Salut, I'm trying to say "Cover joints must be cleaned before replacing cover". 
However, I don't know the word for "cover"; I've tried looking up the word on wordreference and several forums but none apply to a protective cover that you'd find on machines and protect you from the moving parts.

To be clear, right now I have:

> Il faut que nettoyer les joints de ... avant replacer (le/la) ...

My guess for the adjective, it'd be "les joints de protecteur" but I'm still at a loss for the noun. Any insight or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just as a side note, if you're using "Il faut..." followed by an infinitive, you don't need the "que." Just say, "Il faut nettoyer..." :) also, when using "avant..." followed by an infinitive, you need to add "de," so "...avant de re**m**placer..."

Comment: Very informative! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Les joints du capot de protection doivent être nettoyés avant de le remettre en place.